# Does staying in a windowless room have any effect on altitude sickness?

Tags: health, accommodation, la-paz, altitude

I'm planning to stay in a windowless room in La Paz, Bolivia for around 5 days. It's significantly cheaper than the comparable room with windows, and to be honest, the lack of windows for a short period like this does not bother me at all as long as the price/quality ratio is fine. My only concern was whether this would have any effect at all in the altitude sickness I may have developed at that part of the journey? If opening windows actually makes sense in getting more oxygen or otherwise reducing the effects of altitude sickness, then I'm alright with paying more, but if those two are irrelevant, then I'll go with the cheaper option.

Comment: Why do you think a room without window will have any effect on altitude sickness? Have you heard or read it somewhere? Or just guessing?

Comment: Just guessing, couldn't find any information about it online, hopefully that's because it's irrelevant, but maybe someone would have a better idea.

Comment: The only measure I know to decrease the effects of altitude is to chew coca leaves. By the way, that's cheap, but is outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of online resources about altitude sickness prevention. Like [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294072-i5798-k336134-Altitude_sickness-La_Paz_La_Paz_Department.html) or the [NHS](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Altitude-sickness/Pages/Prevention.aspx) (*National Health Services* from the UK government). They all give similar advices, which include, among others:

- Avoid strenuous activities in the first 24/48 hours
- Avoid alcohol and nicotine
- Hydrate yourself more often than you're used to.

  I couldn't find an online resource which mentions windowless room as a measure against altitude sickness. If it was effective, probably someone or some health agency would have suggested it.

  I suggest you to pick the cheaper windowless room and take other more conventional altitude sickness prevention measures.